# Trigger a auto click event in ng-datepicker

Tags: angular, date, typescript

I am working on preparing a calendar in Angular 2 with Typescript. Calendar is getting displayed only after a click but I want the calendar to be displayed on page load without a click. Since I am new to typescript i couldn't do that.

HTML

```
<ng-datepicker [ngModel]="startDatePicker"></ng-datepicker>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
startDatePicker: Date = moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate();
```

[What I need on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKH0t.png)

[What Currently I am getting on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E63zo.png)

Comment: A quick look in the ng-datepicker docs shows a `isOpened` attribute that allows you to show/hide the date picker. Why not just use that? Set `isOpened = true`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker

Comment: Great and simple @narm it worked!!

Comment: Nice, sometimes we get lucky and it's just a simple change. Glad to be of help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ng-datepicker #reference [ngModel]="startDatePicker"></ng-datepicker>
```

Typescript

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
/*some Code*/
ngOnInit() {
@ViewChild('reference')
private datepicker: ElementRef;

this.datepicker.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Comment: bro.. I am getting bug

Answer (score 0):

You could get the component from the template by giving it an id and call the `toggle` method on it.

A generic example would look like this.

The parent component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <toggle-comp #toggleComp></toggle-comp>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit  {
  name:string;

  @ViewChild('toggleComp') public testComp: TestComp;

  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.testComp.toggleState();

    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

The child component (in your case the datepicker).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'toggle-comp',
  template `<div>{{toggle}}</div>`
})
export class TestComp {
 public toggle= false;

  constructor() {}

  public toggleState() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  }
}
```

In your case you'd put the # id on the ng-datepicker.

```
<ng-datepicker #datePicker [ngModel]="startDatePicker"></ng-datepicker>
```

And address it in the component with `@ViewChild('datePicker')`.

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4n1zxJC5axH3Qp57UsZV?p=info).

Comment: this might be for the wrong datepicker (ngb-datepicker).. you can do the same and just set the isOpened for (ng2-datepicker). Or just have a variable that's initially set to true and bind it to that.

Comment: can you explain little brief?

Answer (score 0):

### Material Angular Date Picker Open Onclick or Focus

In  < INPUT >  element add event binding property

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
   <mat-label>Select Date</mat-label>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" (focus)="picker2.open()" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker1 color="secondary"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```